# Null Injector Error in angular material file upload

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, angular-material

I used angular-material-fileupload (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-fileupload) in angular 7 project. But in run time browser throw this exception:

> core.js:5847 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FileUploadInputFor -> ElementRef]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FileUploadInputFor -> ElementRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
>   NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FileUploadInputFor -> ElementRef]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FileUploadInputFor -> ElementRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1225)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1463)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1407)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1311)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1463)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1407)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1311)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:18446)
>       at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:19135)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:19506)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
>       at zone.js:892
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:24328)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)

This is my module:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {ImportBoxComponent} from './import-box.component';
import {SharedLibModule} from '../shared-lib/shared-lib.module';
import {SharedCommonModule} from '../shared-common/shared-common.module';
import {MatFileUploadModule} from 'angular-material-fileupload';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ImportBoxComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedLibModule,
    SharedCommonModule,
    MatFileUploadModule
  ],
  exports: [ImportBoxComponent]
})
export class ImportBoxModule {
}
```

This is my component.html

```
<label for="singleFile">Upload file</label>
<input id="singleFile" type="file [fileUploadInputFor]="fileUploadQueue"/>
<br>
<mat-file-upload-queue #fileUploadQueue [fileAlias]="'file'"               
[httpUrl]="'http://localhost:8180/jax-rs-jersey-application-sample'">
<mat-file-upload [file]="file" [id]="i" *ngFor="let file of fileUploadQueue.files; let i = index">
</mat-file-upload>
```

This is my app.module:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {PagesModule} from './pages/pages.module';
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';
import {SchemaFormModule, WidgetRegistry} from 'ngx-schema-form';
import {GlWidgetRegistry} from './core/widget-registery/widget-registry.service';
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {createTranslateLoader} from './shared/shared-lib/gl-translate/gl-translate.module';
import {AccountModule} from './account/account.module';
import {NgxWebstorageModule} from 'ngx-webstorage';
import {AngularFontAwesomeModule} from 'angular-font-awesome';
import {ToastrModule, ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
import {NotificationInterceptor} from './core/interceptor/notification.interceptor';
import {Ng7MatBreadcrumbService} from 'ng7-mat-breadcrumb';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    AccountModule,
    SharedModule,
    PagesModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    SchemaFormModule.forRoot(),
    NgxWebstorageModule.forRoot({prefix: 'gl', separator: '.'}),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    Ng7MatBreadcrumbService,
    {provide: WidgetRegistry, useClass: GlWidgetRegistry},
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NotificationInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [ToastrService, TranslateService]
    },
  ],
  bootstrap:
    [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

I can't find any useful documentation about angular-material-fileupload package.

Is there any suitable tutorial for this?

Is there any more config for using this package?

Can anyone suggest me a good solution for this issue?

Comment: Can you show your app.module ?

Comment: Have you tried importing `BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule` on your module from '@angular/platform-browser' ?

Comment: I added BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule  still the issue is not resolved @Rambou.